# Latest date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Table Employee

```
ID   Name  Update_date Active Phone_no
1    Dave  02-07-14     Y      99999945
1    Dave  19-12-16     Y      88888888
2    Mike  12-11-17     Y      234234567
2    Mike  12-11-14     Y      345435343
```

What I need is:Select * from employee where id in (1,2);
Above query will give me above table as it is.
But what I need is

```
ID   Name  Update_date Active Phone_no
1    Dave  19-12-16     Y      88888888
2    Mike  12-11-17     Y      234234567
```

For every ID it search it should take latest date.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tuple and a subselect with in clause  and group by

```
select * from my_table 
where ( id, Update_date) in (  select  id, max(update_date)
                               from my_table
                               group by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Chedk this .

```
 select * from 

 (    Select  ID,Name,row_number() over (partition by ID order by Update_date desc ) as row ,Active ,Phone_no ,
        Update_date 

        from employee  
)  a where id in (1,2) and row='1'
```

Comment: The OP  need  all the colums .. (phone_no too)

Comment: `and row='1'` ... but row_number() produces a number, not a string. That should be `and row = 1`